# How to calculate time in minutes in excel from date value and time value

Tags: excel

I've been running through several methods, but can't seem to adapt any to my needs. So experts I seek your knowledge... In excel I have 2 date fields and 2 time fields in a 24 hour format. I need to calculate the total duration between start and end date & time in Minutes...

Example dataset:

```
+----+-------+----------------+----------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| ID | Level | Date Submitted | Time Submitted | End Date Submitted | End Time Submitted |
+----+-------+----------------+----------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|  1 | High  | 9/1/2017       | 13:58:56       | 9/1/2017           | 14:23:42           |
|  2 | Med   | 9/2/2017       | 4:04:23        | 9/3/2017           | 20:41:33           |
+----+-------+----------------+----------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

For ID 1 I'm trying to get a result field value = 25

For ID 2 I'm trying to get a result field value = 2437

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy, *assuming your data is formatted as date and time*. Excel automatically handles these data types very nicely.

Something like this would do it:

```
= (<end date> + <end time> - (<start date> + <start time>))*24*60
```

See example below.

[image]

Then you can round up or down as necessary using `ROUND`, `FLOOR`, or `CEILING` function, whichever works best for your application.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your ID header is in A1 you can use the following formula: =ROUND(((E2+F2)-(C2+D2))*60*24,0).

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the columns are exactly like in your example, you can use this:

```
= (TEXT(E2,"mm/dd/yyyy")-TEXT(C2,"mm/dd/yyyy")+(F2-D2))*24*60
```

First we need to check whether the dates are identical.

1. Subtract the dates (the result is in "days" unit).
2. Similarly, subtract the hours (this result is also in "days" unit).
3. Multiply the result by `24*60`, to get result in "minutes".

If you want, you can wrap it all with some rounding functions, as other users already explained pretty thoroughly.

let me know if you need further explanation.

Comment: Seems unnecessary to check if the dates are identical, considering if they are, then the difference between them is just 0, thus not affecting the calculation (since adding 0 to the final result will not change the result).

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 You're absolutely right! I've edited my answer